# SQL statement Max(Count(*))

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically I have a review table for product. The attributes are reviewID, reviewCustName, reviewText, productID. So I wonder is there any ways to count the product with most reviews? Here is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT productID, count(*) AS mostReviews, MAX(mostReviews) FROM sm_review GROUP BY productID;
```

I wonder is it possible to write such SQL statement? Or i there any better way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL - Displaying entries that are the max of a count?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159928/sql-displaying-entries-that-are-the-max-of-a-count)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to get the result. This gets the total count for each product but when you order the count in a descending order and apply `LIMIT 1` it returns only the product with the most reviews:

```
select count(*) total
from sm_review
group by productId
order by total desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It should just be;

```
SELECT count(*) AS num_reviews FROM sm_review 
GROUP BY productID ORDER BY num_reviews DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Note the `ORDER BY num_reviews` and the `LIMIT 1` which limits the number of results.

Comment: But I only need the product with most reviews. So I think I need the Max() ?

Comment: Added a `LIMIT 1` if you only need the top 1.