# SQL Query to find MAX values based upon count and some filters

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count

Table looks like below :

```
/* Create a table called test */
CREATE TABLE test(Id integer PRIMARY KEY,Col_Key text, Ng text, node text);

/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO test VALUES(1,'key1','g1','n2');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(2,'key1','g2','n3');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(3,'key2','g3','n1');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(4,'key2','g4','n1');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(5,'key3','g5','n1');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(6,'key3','g6','n2');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(7,'key4','g7','n1');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(8,'key4','g8','n1');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(9,'key5','g8','n4');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(10,'key5','g9','n4');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(11,'key6','g10','n4');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(12,'key6','g11','n4');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(13,'key7','g11','n4');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(14,'key9','q11','n3');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(15,'key9','q11','n2');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(16,'key10','q12','n1');
COMMIT;
```

I'm trying to get values from the node column which have a maximum count and whose Ng value starts with g.

I have done something like this:

```
SELECT TEMP.node,COUNT(TEMP.node) FROM (SELECT Col_Key,Ng,node 
from test WHERE (Ng LIKE 'g%')) TEMP GROUP BY TEMP.node;
```

which gives below result:

[image]

But, in the result I want only n4 and n1 in result (only node column not count) as they have the maximum count. I am unable to add this part in my query. Please help.

Above data is just a small piece of data but i will have thousands of rows in my SQL table, so my query should be efficient.

PS  :- I tried doing below :

```
SELECT TEMP2.node,TEMP2.CNT FROM (SELECT TEMP.node,COUNT(TEMP.node) AS CNT FROM (SELECT Col_Key,Ng,node 
from test WHERE (Ng LIKE 'g%')) TEMP GROUP BY TEMP.node) TEMP2 WHERE TEMP2.CNT = (SELECT MAX(TEMP2.CNT) FROM TEMP2);
```

but last part of the query with where clause is wrong as it is unable to find table TEMP2.

but this WHERE cluase kinds of give idea what i want exaclty.

RESULT should be :

```
node 
n1
n4
```

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159928/sql-displaying-entries-that-are-the-max-of-a-count/14236780

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a subquery for your query:

```
select node, count(*) 
from test
where Ng LIKE 'g%'
group by node;
```

Getting one maximum is easy (using `limit`), but you want all of them.  One method uses a subquery and a `having` clause:

```
select node, count(*) 
from test
where Ng LIKE 'g%'
group by node
having count(*) = (select count(*)
                   from test t2
                   where t2.Ng LIKE 'g%'
                   group by t2.node
                   order by count(*) desc
                   limit 1
                  );
```

This is more complicated than it needs to be because MySQL (pre-8.0) supports neither window functions nor CTEs.  Happily, the syntax is simpler in MySQL 8+.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
SELECT
  t.node,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  test t
WHERE
  t.Ng like 'g%'
GROUP BY
  t.node
HAVING
  COUNT(*) = (
    SELECT 
      MAX(a.count_of_nodes)
    FROM
    (
      SELECT
        node,
        COUNT(*) AS count_of_nodes
      FROM
        test
      WHERE
        Ng like 'g%'
      GROUP BY
        node
    ) a
  )
;
```

Good luck!

Comment: WHY row_num = 5?

Comment: Can someone suggest which will be the most efficient way out of all these for a table which haas large amount of data?

Comment: How much data? What's your context for needing these results?

Comment: thousands  to millions of rows

Comment: Nice and what's the context? Nightly report? On the fly BI query? Application server (hopefully not)?

Comment: on the fly BI query

Comment: You'll be fine then with this type of query then. Can you give it a go so we have a starting point and if the performance is unacceptable we can optimize from there?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temptable to handle this situation easily and readable like below:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temptable AS (
  SELECT TEMP.node,COUNT(TEMP.node) as cnt FROM (SELECT Col_Key,Ng,node 
  from test WHERE (Ng LIKE 'g%')) TEMP GROUP BY TEMP.node
)
select node, cnt
from temptable t
where cnt = (select max(cnt) from temptable)
```

See: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e749de/1/0